# Can I check if a session is still available without renewing it?

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-4.5

I was going to write some code that opens a modal box warning the user that their session is about to expire. But seeing as how there may be circumstances where the session terminates early, I'd kind of like to check that their session is still available before showing this dialog.

Is there a way I can check to see if the user's session is still active without renewing it?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/ ? I have used it in past. That may reduce your efforts significantly. The way to check if session is active or not depends on where your session information is.

Comment: @Yogiraj - I've looked at that one before, but it really solves a different problem. My JavaScript is going to be custom.